# Clustered indexing is now must - why?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, azure-sql-database, index

Earlier,  there were non-conclusive to me debates / discussions on whether to (always) engage / avoid clustered indexes.

Well, I understood that they are to be used sometimes with proper + specific purposes and context.

[SQL Azure Database Clustered Index Requirement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336245.aspx#cir):

> "SQL Azure does not support tables without clustered indexes. A table must have a clustered index. If a table is created without a clustered constraint, a clustered index must be created before an insert operation is allowed on the table"

does not fit in the previous conclusions, rationale and explanations.

What is the rationale, that I have missed from prev explanations, of rigidly imposing ubiquity of clustered indexes without any exceptions?

Comment: Note that in v12 of the Azure SQL Database Service, you may have a table without a clustered index.

Answer (score 11):

Read [Inside SQL Azure](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/inside-sql-azure.aspx):

> SQL Azure provides logical databases
>   for application data storage. In
>   reality, each subscriber’s data is
>   actually stored multiple times,
>   replicated across three SQL Server
>   databases that are distributed across
>   three physical servers in a single
>   data center. Many subscribers may
>   share the same physical database.

Clustered keys are required so that the three replicas of your data can be kept in sync. W/o  a key, is impossible to know which rows were updated. Heaps (tables w/o a clustered index) have only physical 'keys' (fileid:pageid:slot) and since your 3 replicas of the logical database *share physical database* with other logical databases the physical address on one server has no meaning on the other replicas, hence heaps could not possibly be replicated.

Comment: A (logical) key doesn't have to reside in a clustered index. It could be nonclustered. Perhaps the real reason why a (presumably unique?) clustered index is required is that heaps use RIDs whereas unique clustered indexes do not. Is that what you meant?

Comment: From the linked document: "The underlying high availability and replication technology in SQL Azure is based on replicating B-Tree rows.". So even if a heap would have a NC key, you could only replicate the NC, but not the heap itself.

Comment: Another source: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/why-do-i-need-a-clustered-index/

Answer (score 1):

Azure is a distributed, cloud based system on remote servers.  The data will likely be stored on multiple drives/servers, and it would be extremely inefficient to do this on a heap (since the system will need to know which machine to check, and without a clustered index this is a resource-intensive operation).

The clustered index provides a lookup for all rows and all other indexes on the table, so without one every operation in azure would be a table scan across multiple machines.

Comment: That *could* be true, but at the moment is not. Read article I linked, it explains how the request routing works and why your queries run always on one single box and never span multiple servers. Ie. there is no sharding.